# how do I get my button to have a sprite without setting a width or using text indent?

Tags: css

I'm thinking this can be done with some sort of inline-block magic? maybe?

idk.. but basically, the text and the sprite should be inline.

right now, they are not: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/qvZkK/2/

html:

```
<a href="" class="action_button" rel="facebox" style="">
    <span class="button_sprite_x"></span>
    Delete
</a>
```

Comment: Is just the text ("Delete") supposed to be underlined?

Comment: normally no. but that is the default style of the anchor tag text. adding text-decoration: none; gets rid of the underline o.o

Comment: So you want the underline to never be there? I'm confused as to what the button should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will your layout allow you to float it?

```
.action_button span.button_sprite_x,
.action_button span.button_sprite_plus,
.action_button span.button_sprite_duplicate,
.action_button span.button_sprite_star{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  float: left; /* Added float */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qvZkK/3/

UPDATE:

Ah, but you probably want the sprite to be within the `a` element's background. A combination of `display: inline-block` and `float: left` does that.

```
.action_button {
  display: inline-block; /* Add display: inline-block to .action_button */
}

.action_button span.button_sprite_x,
.action_button span.button_sprite_plus,
.action_button span.button_sprite_duplicate,
.action_button span.button_sprite_star{
  display: inline-block; /* And add display: inline-block here, also */
  float: left; /* Added float */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qvZkK/4/

Comment: close... I need the sprite inside the butto though =\ I've found that I can set the sprite to be display: table-cell, and the anchor to be display: table;, but then the height of the button gets changed (button height is 18, expands to 22 with the sprite inside).

Comment: @TheLindyHop Yeah, just realized that was probably what you wanted. See update.

Comment: It works but it's not really the best way to do it IMO. You are creating a span just for an image which is not semantic. Put the text inside the span and add some left-padding and line-height equal to that of the image. That way you won't have to worry about lining things up.

Answer (score 0):

put the text inside the span: http://jsfiddle.net/qvZkK/7/

- Float the `a` tag to the left
- Put the text **inside** the `<span>` i.e. `<span> DELETE </span>`
- Remove width from the `.button_sprite_x` class and give it `padding-left: 25px`
- Make sure background image is set to no-repeat

Looks like you can figure out how to style it ok yourself from there.
PS - I added margin to the link to make it easier to see, you probably want to remove that though.

Comment: without using background position, is there another way to center the sprite? cause with the currently selected answer to this question, I'd need to use position: relative, and nudge the sprite 2px from the top and left.

Comment: Yes, this is probably something to do with the line-height of `.action_button`. Try `line-height: 20px;`.